# Add register now link only on login page Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I had to split the login and register pages on my WooCommerce site.
Using this code this was achieved

```
add_shortcode( 'wc_reg_form_bbloomer', 'bbloomer_separate_registration_form' );
    
function bbloomer_separate_registration_form() {
   if ( is_admin() ) return;
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return;
   ob_start();
 
   // NOTE: THE FOLLOWING <FORM></FORM> IS COPIED FROM woocommerce\templates\myaccount\form-login.php
   // IF WOOCOMMERCE RELEASES AN UPDATE TO THAT TEMPLATE, YOU MUST CHANGE THIS ACCORDINGLY
 
   do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' );
 
   ?>
      <form method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-register register" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_tag' ); ?> >
 
         <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>
 
         <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>
 
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
               <label for="reg_username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
               <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
            </p>
 
         <?php endif; ?>
 
         <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="reg_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
         </p>
 
         <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>
 
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
               <label for="reg_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
               <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" />
            </p>
 
         <?php else : ?>
 
            <p><?php esc_html_e( 'A password will be sent to your email address.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
 
         <?php endif; ?>
 
         <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>
 
         <p class="woocommerce-FormRow form-row">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
            <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-register__submit" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Next', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Next', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
         </p>
 
         <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>
 
      </form>
 
   <?php
     
   return ob_get_clean();
}
```

However the issue was there was no Register option on the Login page so I placed one using Elementor as it is page builder for the site.

I've placed the Register now button on the My Account page since that is where it then directs to Login page but because of this it is showing the Register Now button even inside the My Account dashboard and on the edit address part. I need it to show only on the Login page.

Comment: thinking if maybe it can detect when someone is logged in then it can not show the button ?